# Java type erasure compile issue in ant

Tags: java, ant

In a java class, I have an overloaded method like this:

```
method1(List<Details1HO> input){};
```

and `method1(List<Details2HO> input){};`
Both `Details2HO` and `Details1HO` extend the same class `DetailsHO`.
RAD builds the class fine, but ant gives error:

```
name clash: method1(java.util.List<Details1HO>) and method2(java.util.List<Details1HO>) have the same erasure
```

The Java version is 1.5 both in ant and in RAD
EDIT: The methods have different return types
EDIT #2: Real error:

```
name clash: mapToDO(java.util.List<com.bmo.ctp.alerts.businessobjects.user.hibernate.DeliveryDomainRestrictionHO>) and mapToDO(java.util.List<com.bmo.ctp.alerts.businessobjects.subscription.hibernate.SubscriptionDetailsHO>) have the same erasure
```

Real declaration:

```
public static DeliveryDomainRestrictionDO[] mapToDO(List<DeliveryDomainRestrictionHO> deliveryDomainRestrictions){}

public static List<SubscriptionSummaryDO> mapToDO(List<SubscriptionDetailsHO> input) {}
```

Comment: Never mind `ant`, what does `javac` say? And your declarations are inconsistent with the error message, what is the actual code?

Comment: @Kilian : ant is just a build tool. Not a compiler. It uses javac.

Comment: Any hope of seeing the _real_ declarations and the _real_ error message?  As Kilian says, the question has written is inconsistent so it is impossible to tell what is really going on.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that RAD will build this; it shouldn't.  It's not legal to have a class that looks like:

```
class Foo {
  public void foo(List<A> as);
  public void foo(List<B> bs);
}
```

because, due to [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), they both have the exact same signature at runtime:

```
class Foo {
  public void foo(List);
  public void foo(List);
}
```

When you have this sort of problem, it typically means you're trying to do something more complicated than you actually need to :)  In any case, you will need to disambiguate these somehow.

Comment: Ok..withut further investigation, we decided to rename the method to be safe. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Java doesn't allow overloading using only different generic parameters. From the runtimes point of view both are just methods that take a list as parameter.

Comment: How come it compiles well on RAD?

Comment: @Kaushik If it does, RAD is in violation of the Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution to this is to change the method signatures. Currently, the signatures of both your methods are the same(AT runtime that is).